# Make a variable height div?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I've been trying to make a wordpress template. Everything was fine, but when you have more than 2 long posts, the text go out the div. There's any way I can make the div height variable?

Comment: sure, fix the css... divs are NATURALLY variable-height. If yours aren't,then you've got something overriding that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can set `min-height` in css instead of `height` .
or u can use `overflow-y:scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

there's definitely more than just that... some other css attributes are probably causing this as marc suggested. Check the height, overflow, and any such relevant attributes.